# How Did I Simultaneously Make Two Identical Revisions?

Tags: bug, editing

I was just attempting to edit [Why don't many dictionaries list “would= to be willing”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/431778/) to make the information added in revision 5 a little more presentable, and something rather strange happened. For some strange reason, there is a [Revision 7](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/431778/7) attributed to me, that happened concurrently with [revision 6](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/431778/6):

[image: This is a screenshot that shows the defect]

I am not quite sure why this happened. I am relatively confident that it should not have happened for two reasons: One is that usually an editor gets a grace period of about 5 minutes before any additional revisions are added, and these revisions are not even a minute apart. The other is that revision 7 has no content change from revision 6, and [I thought that edits required at least six characters to be changed to prevent trivial edits](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10124/124936).

I suppose the fact that a moderator decided to close the question as I was applying my edit may have something to do with it, but I do not know what that is. I read the exceptions for the grace period in [this meta F.A.Q.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work/21789#21789) and nothing about closure is mentioned. I also only submitted my edit once, so i would not expect any of the conditions to apply anyway.

I sincerely doubt that it should have happened, so why did it happen?

Comment: Something similar happened for me [once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300007/309993) or [twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300226/309993).

Comment: Note that only suggested edits have the "6 chars" rule.

Comment: The closure (at 12:54) did not coincide with your edit (timed at 12:49). Something similar appears to have happened to revisions 4 and 5, which are more than five minutes apart and yet somehow confused together.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I see nothing wrong with rev 4 and 5. After submitting the rev 4, the editor immediately chose to edit again, so the edit summary was automatically copied from the rev 4. And when it was finally submitted, it crossed the 5 min mark, and ended up as a separate edit, albeit with the same summary.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Perhaps my language was too imprecise. I started editing before the question was closed, and by the time I finished it was closed, so I  saw the status change after I applied my edit. I find NVZ's first link somewhat interesting, because there his screenshot  shows that his doubled revision also happened with 6th revision like mine. Hmm.

Comment: I would interpret the logs to show you committed your edit 5 mins before closure. Perhaps things go wrong if they occur simultaneously.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I see that Tonepoet linked to your other meta answer about the 6 chars minimum edits. I must say... you have made a small error. Edits by privileged users (not just mods and authors) do not need to follow the minimum 6 chars edit rule. Please correct your other answer.